# attribute tuple doc.ents is writable in spacy?

Tags: spacy

I'm a python and Spacy newbie, and i'm learning Spacy with the spacy course https://course.spacy.io/es/chapter2. In this lesson there is an example like this:

```
# Import the Doc and Span classes
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span

# The words and spaces to create the doc from
words = ["Hello", "world", "!"]
spaces = [True, False, False]

# Create a doc manually
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)

# Create a span manually
span = Span(doc, 0, 2)

# Create a span with a label
span_with_label = Span(doc, 0, 2, label="GREETING")

# Add span to the doc.ents
doc.ents = [span_with_label]
```

I had understood that doc.ents is a python tuple, and therefore it must be inmutable. How it's possible then to add elements to it like in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tuple itself, as an object in memory, is inmutable, but in that final line, the code creates a completely new tuple and assigns the `.ents` variable to that new immutable tuple, it does not manipulate the original tuple.

Here is an illustration:

Create a tuple and print its type to confirm that it is indeed a tuple:

```
>>> test_tuple = (3, 4, 7, 5)
>>> type(test_tuple)
tuple
```

Try to change the first element of the tuple:

```
>>> test_tuple[0] = "hello"
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Now try to assign a new tuple to the same variable:

```
>>> test_tuple = ("hello", 4, 7, 5)
>>> print(test_tuple)
('hello', 4, 7, 5)
```

Works just fine! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Then, the comment #Add span to the doc.ents could be #replace doc.ents with new of only one entity, i think.

Comment: You are technically correct, but I guess the tutorial is not incorrect, either, because this example starts with an empty model, so there are no entities to replace. If you print `doc.ents` before the last line, you'd get `()`.